# Google says "duplicate store codes" when updating the opening hours for hundreds of business locations via CSV

Tags: google, google-my-business

I am trying to edit the hours for our locations (206 locations).  The hours will all change to the same for all stores.  I downloaded our locations to CSV, made the edits, but when I try to upload them it says it has duplicate store codes.  Has anyone done this before?  I read on the google documents that bulk edit was available.

Anyone have a step by step for this process?

https://support.google.com/business/answer/3217744?hl=en
https://support.google.com/business/answer/4577733

[image]

Comment: I assume you've check your CSV for duplicate store codes?